# Az-delivery board and "Fatal error occured"

Tags: fatal-error, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

Recently, I purchased an AZ-Delivery board and I am eager to delve into Arduino programming. While attempting to run a basic example, the LED blink, I encountered the following error:
"A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received."
Despite my efforts to change the boards on the Arduino IDE, none of them seem to be resolving the issue.
Notably, I am using a USB hub to connect the Arduino to my MacBook Air.
I have ensured the correct Port is selected in the Arduino IDE by ejecting and re-inserting the USB.
All relevant figures are attached to this message. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in overcoming this problem.

After consulting various sources, I attempted holding down the button for a few seconds upon encountering the "connecting..." message. I also uninstalled and reinstalled the ESP32. Furthermore, I searched through the documentation but was unable to locate the relevant information for the board.